# GLib - invoke callback for all instances of a class

Tags: callback, signals, glib, gobject

I started to look into Glib signals. In my scenario I want to connect several instances of a class to a signal and if one of those instances calls g_signal_emit(...), the provided callback function should be called for all instances of that class. Let me try to explain this with an example.

What I tried is to create two instance of a class A (A0 and A1). 
Class A registers a very simple signal in its *_class_init* function.

```
 file_signals[0] = g_signal_newv("a_signal",
      G_TYPE_FROM_CLASS(ACLASS),
      G_SIGNAL_ACTION,
      NULL          /* closure */,
      NULL          /* accumulator */,
      NULL          /* accumulator data */,
      NULL          /* C marshaller */,
      G_TYPE_NONE   /* return_type */,
      0             /* n_params */,
      NULL);        /* argument types*/
```

Then I connect a simple callback function (cb_a) for both instances A0 and A1 to the signal "a_signal". (For example in the *_instance_init* function)

```
g_signal_connect(A0, "a_signal", (GCallback)cb_a, NULL);
g_signal_connect(A1, "a_signal", (GCallback)cb_a, NULL); ,
```

where cb_a is a function defined in A.c:

```
static void cb_a(void)
{
printf("cb_a called!\");
}
```

What happens now is that if I invoke

```
g_signal_emit(A0, file_signals[0], 0);
```

is that only the callback associated to A0 is invoked. I couldn´t figure out how to call the function for each instance of A with e.g. a single call to g_signal_emit(...)?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That’s not how GObject signals work. A signal is a one-to-many notification from a single class instance to all the connected callbacks for that class instance. If you want to emit the `A::a_signal` signal from several instances of the class, you need to call `g_signal_emit()` for each of those instances.

Note that `g_signal_emit()` is only meant to be called from within the implementation of a class, not from code outside that class.

One approach to your problem is to have a separate class (let’s call it `Signaller`) with a signal on it, to store a reference to a single instance of `Signaller` within `A0` and `A1`, and to connect `a_cb` to that instance within each of `A0` and `A1`. To notify all instances of the `A` class, emit `Signaller::a_signal` on the single `Signaller` instance.

However, without more concrete information about the particular problem you’re trying to solve, it’s hard to say what the right architecture is. My suggestion above may not be the most appropriate solution.

Comment: Thank you Philip,

I will think about your suggestion with the "Signaller" class. What I am actually trying to achieve is to instantiate several instances of class A that contain a function which I would like to pass a message to (e.g. void cb_a(parameters, message)).
This message should come as a payload when I emit the signal. All cb_a functions of all instances should receive the message and parse it. The content of the message will then allow the instance to decide if the message was sent to them or if they should ignore the content.

Comment: I added the signaller class and it works like a charm. Thanks!